# Apend multiple variables

Tags: jquery

**I have got this table:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Paul Stevenson</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <td>28. 09. 1978</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**And I want to add some functions to my table:**

```
var toolbar = $("<div />").css({
  "padding": "5px",
  "background" : "#F8F8F8",
  "position" : "absolute",
  "borderRadius" : "5px",
})
var link = $("<a />").css({
    "display" : "block",
    "height" : "17px",
    "width" : "17px",
    "position" : "relative"}).on("click", function() {
  $(this).animate({bottom: "-2px"}, 20 ).animate({bottom: "0"}, 20 );
});
```

Here is toolbar and link. Toolbar should append on mouse enter and it has a link inside it.

```
    $('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
          if (e.type === 'mouseenter') { $(this).append( toolbar ); }
          else { $(this).find( $("div") ).remove() }
        });

toolbar.html( gmaps );
```

There are more types of link types. I make it like this

```
var gmaps = link.css({ "background" : "red",});
var google = link.css({"background" : "blue",});
```

How can I make append more link types?

```
toolbar.html( gmaps + google );
```

Doesn't work. Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJMQYE?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few modifications to your code as follows:

1) Create the multiple link object via `$.clone()` to avoid overwriting same DOM element like:

```
var gmaps = link.clone().css({ "background" : "red",});
var google = link.clone().css({"background" : "blue",});
```

2) While adding these links to `toolbar`; go for `$.append()` function call so that it will get appended at the bottom of same container as follows:

```
toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google );
```

Please have a look at complete source code at updated codepen link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mepzxd?editors=0010

Comment: Good, but I have many types of links, is it necesary to still repeat append?

Comment: @KarolinaTicha - Yes, By calling `var gmaps = ` we are just creating a javascript variable. By calling `append` we are attaching it into the DOM.